# How to disable the ⌥-Space fullscreen Quick Look shortcut?

Tags: macos, big-sur, keybindings, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

#### How to reproduce

When hitting <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> on a file or folder, Quick Look goes into fullscreen.

[image]

[Wikipedia's "Quick Look" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) lists these shortcuts.

[image]

#### What I'm trying to do

I'd like to disable this (extremely dominant) shortcut because I want to re-use it to open a new iTerm window on the focused location with an automator script.

I never use the QL fullscreen, since regular Quick Look is entirely enough for me.

#### What I tried

I can't find the shortcut in `keyboard > shortcuts` and have not found any options that let me configure QL.

`qlmanage` also doesn't seem to give me obvious options to configure the keybindings

```bsh
▶ qlmanage -h
Usage: qlmanage [OPTIONS] path...
    -h      Display this help
    -r      Force reloading Generators list
    -r cache    Reset thumbnail disk cache
    -m [name ...]   Display statistics about quicklookd. Stats names:
            * plugins   Show the generators list
            * server    Show quicklookd life information
            * memory    Show quicklookd memory consumption
            * burst     Show statistics about the last burst
            * threads   Show concurrent accesses stats
            * other     Show other information about quicklookd
    -p      Compute previews of the documents
    -t      Compute thumbnails of the documents
    -x      Use quicklookd (remote computation)
    -i      Compute thumbnail in icon mode
    -s size     Size for the thumbnail
    -f factor   Scale factor for the thumbnail
    -F factor   Scale factor for the thumbnail, draw downscaled and compare to 1x
    -z      Display generation performance info (don't display thumbnails)
    -o dir      Output result in dir (don't display thumbnails or previews)
    -c contentType  Force the content type used for the documents
    -g generator    Force the generator to use
```

I'm skimmed also over the following documents:

- [Quick Look Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH1-SW1)
- [Quick Look Framework Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook)
- [Apple Developer: Human Interface Guidelines - Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/keyboard/)

So far, no luck on how to change the key bindings

#### Question

How do I modify Quick Look Shortcuts or disable them?